# Error generando claves: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, criptografía

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas de criptografía, al ejecutar la siguiente línea de código:

```
Signature sgn = Signature.getInstance( "MD5" );
```

Obtengo el error:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD5 Signature not available

He probado SHA, SHA256, ...
Siempre es lo mismo, cuando en otros casos no fallaba, por ejemplo:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Signature;

public class TestAlgoriths {

    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        
        try {
            MessageDigest msgDg = MessageDigest.getInstance( "MD5" );
            
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.err.println(
                "ERR -> Generando MessageDigest... \n" + e.toString( ));
        }
        
        try {
            Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance( "MD5" );
            
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.err.println(
                "ERR -> Generando Signature... \n" + e.toString( ));
        }
    }
    
} //class
```

Si puedo obtener la instancia de *MessageDigest* usando MD5.

Firmas de los algoritmos disponibles:

```
MD2withRSA
MD5andSHA1withRSA
MD5withRSA
NONEwithDSA
NONEwithECDSA
NONEwithRSA
SHA1withDSA
SHA1withECDSA
SHA1withRSA
SHA224withDSA
SHA224withECDSA
SHA224withRSA
SHA256withDSA
SHA256withECDSA
SHA256withRSA
SHA384withECDSA
SHA384withRSA
SHA512withECDSA
SHA512withRSA
```

Las obtengo con la siguiente clase:

```
/**
 * Gets a list of signature algorithms supported by your Java installation
 * From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922727
 *
 */
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Provider.Service;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class ShowAlgoriths {
    
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        
        Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
        System.out.println("Disponibles " + providers.length + " providers.");
        
        TreeSet<String> algorithms = new TreeSet<>();
        
        for (Provider provider : providers) {
            for (Service service : provider.getServices( )) {
                
                if (service.getType().equals("Signature")) {
                    algorithms.add(service.getAlgorithm( ));
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("\nAlgoritmos: ");
        for (String algorithm : algorithms) {
            System.out.println(algorithm);
        }
    }
    
} //class
```

***Editado:***

> Estoy trabajando en Windows7 con Netbeans 8.2
>
> java version "1.8.0_161"
>
> Me lleve los ficheros compilados a otro ordenador, ejecute en consola y mismo resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad el problema no es al obtener `MessageDigest` de `MD5` es al tratar de obtener la firma de `MD5`, en realidad esto es incorrecto:

```
  Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance( "MD5" );
```

La firma para `MD5` se debe obtener de esta forma:

```
  Signature dsa  = Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA");
```

---

Esta es una prueba generar la instancia de la firma con DSA, SHA1withRSA y MD5withRSA, incluso puedo imprimir su algoritmo y su proveedor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Lo mismo digo yo. Bueno, probe con "MD5withDSA" antes y seguía con el mismo error. Si pruebo con "MD5withRSA" cambia el mensaje un poco: *java.security.InvalidKeyException: Not an RSA key: DSA* Estoy trabajando en Windows, lo añadire a la pregunta por si acaso...

Comment: @Orici que IDE y que versión de Java usas?

Comment: Añadida version Java e IDE al final de la pregunta

Comment: @Orici es muy raro ya que incluso veo que tienes el algoritmo "MD5withRSA", traté de realizar lo mismo en Netbeans 8.2 y puedo generar la instancia de la firma incluso genere instancias de DSA y SHA1withRSA y puedo imprimir su algoritmo y su proveedor, ve mi actualización.

Comment: al final funciono con "SHA1withDSA", no se que pasa con el resto que parece que si tengo. Saludos.

Comment: @Orici es un poco raro que no funcionara ya que imprimiste lso algoritmos y en realidad existe "SHA1withRSA"

Comment: son los rayos cósmicos seguramente